# How to capture the Assertion Error which is displaying in console

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm using assert for verifying two value, so if my test case fail and in console it show why it is failed (expected [Passwo] but found [Password]). I want to capture this Assertion Error so that I can write this error message in Excel sheet.

I also tried try catch block but it is also not working, below is my code for single assertion.

```
try {
        //Password
        String PasswordFromApplication;
         assertion.assertEquals(PasswordFromApplication=login.getPasswordNameLabel(), ReadValueFromID.getValue("LoginWindowPasswordLabelID"));

        String expectedKeyFromExcel2=ReadKeyFromID.getKeyValue("LoginWindowPasswordLabelID");

        String valueFromXml2=ReadXmlData.getValue(expectedKeyFromExcel2);

        assertion.assertEquals(PasswordFromApplication, valueFromXml2);

        System.out.println("LoginWindowPasswordLabelID PASSED");
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("FAILED DUE TO "+e);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `java.lang.Throwable` class is the root class of Java Exception hierarchy which is inherited by two subclasses: `Exception` and `Error`. A hierarchy of Java Exception classes are given below:

[image]

> executing assertion, it is believed to be true. If it fails, JVM
>   throws an error named **AssertionError**. AssertionError class is
>   inherit **Error** class so you can use **Throwable**, **Error** and
>   **AssertionError** to catch Assertion error

**So catch block should be:**

```
catch (AssertionError ae) {
        System.out.println("Assertion Error is  "+ae);
    }
```

**OR**

```
catch (Error e) {
        System.out.println("Assertion Error is  "+e);
    }
```

**OR**

```
catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("Assertion Error is  "+t);
    }
```

Comment: helpfull, so suppose I have multiple assertions and if more than one assertion fails how can I store there cause of failure in a different variable. above code help me to store all the error message in one variable, but I want to store it into different so that I can put that particular error information in excel sheet in a different row. I'm doing a localization testing, I'm localizing UI of the application so if some contain fail I need to store the cause of the failure in excel sheet.

Comment: Surely I can't say but softAssertion can help you in this scenario. I have faced this situation but in that case I have  invoked function responsible to update status in excel  in @AfterMethod so you can updated reason of fail. You can also call this function in catch block.

Comment: If this solution solve your query so please accept it as answer to help SO community. It will help people with same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should catch AssertionError instead of Exception, AssertionError  doesn't inherit from Exception (it inherit from Error) and that is the reason your catch block doesn't catch the exception.

working code:

```
try {
        //Password
        String PasswordFromApplication;
         assertion.assertEquals(PasswordFromApplication=login.getPasswordNameLabel(), ReadValueFromID.getValue("LoginWindowPasswordLabelID"));
        String expectedKeyFromExcel2=ReadKeyFromID.getKeyValue("LoginWindowPasswordLabelID");
        String valueFromXml2=ReadXmlData.getValue(expectedKeyFromExcel2);
        assertion.assertEquals(PasswordFromApplication, valueFromXml2);
        System.out.println("LoginWindowPasswordLabelID PASSED");
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        System.out.println("FAILED DUE TO "+e);
    }
```